# C++ Walkthrough Woes:

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I thought I was good at this programming thing, until I hit this devil of a walkthrough that is (conveniently) absent from my textbook.

My guess is something about a copy constructor.

It involves two classes, *Paragraph* and *Word*.  There is a dynamic array of *Word* objects inside each *Paragraph* class.  The trouble is when the **Paragraph class += operator overload method** is called in main() - a professor comments that it calls the *Word* constructor, then the *Word* = operator.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't there be another operator overload to handle a *Word* object on the left and a *string* on the right??

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 #define WIDTH 8

 class Word {
     char* text;
     int nletters;
   public:
     Word() {
         text = NULL;
         nletters = 0;
         cout << 'W';
     }
     Word(const char* s) {
         nletters = 0;
         while(s[nletters] != '\0')
             nletters++;
         text = new char[nletters];
         for (int i = 0; i < nletters; i++)
             text[i] = s[i];
         cout << 'X';
     }
     Word(const Word& p) {
         text = NULL;
         *this = p;  // calls assignment operator below
         cout << 'Y';
     }
     ~Word() {
         if (text != NULL) delete [] text;
         cout << "~W" << nletters;
     }
     Word& operator=(const Word& p) {
         if (this != &p) {
             if (text != NULL) delete [] text;
             nletters = 0;
             if (p.text != NULL) {
                 text = new char[p.nletters];
                 while(nletters < p.nletters) {
                     text[nletters] = p.text[nletters];
                     nletters++;
                 }
             }
             else
                 text = NULL;
         }
         cout << 'V';
         return *this;
     }
     int nLetters() const { return nletters; }
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Word& w) {
         if (w.text != NULL)
             for (int i = 0; i < w.nletters; i++)
                 os << w.text[i];
         else
             os << "***";
         os << ' ';
         return os;
     }
 };

 class Paragraph {
     Word* word;
     int mwords;
     int nwords;
     int width;
   public:
     Paragraph() {
         word  = NULL;
         width = WIDTH;
         nwords = 0;
         mwords = 0;
         cout << 'P' << endl;
     }
     Paragraph(const Paragraph& c) {
         word  = NULL;
         *this = c;  // calls assignment operator below
         cout << "cP";
     }
     Paragraph& operator=(const Paragraph& c) {
         if (this != &c) {
             if (word != NULL) delete [] word;
             if (c.word != NULL) {
                 word = new Word[c.mwords];
                 cout << endl;
                 for (int i = 0; i < c.nwords; i++)
                     word[i] = c.word[i];  // calls Word assignment operator
             }
             else
                 word = NULL;
             width  = c.width;
             nwords = c.nwords;
             mwords = c.mwords;
         }
         cout << "=P";
         return *this;
     }
     ~Paragraph() {
         if (word != NULL) delete [] word;
         cout << '\n' << nwords << "~P" << endl;
     }
     void make(int m) {
         if (word == NULL) {
             word = new Word[m];
             mwords = m;
             nwords = 0;
             width  = WIDTH;
         }
     }
     void setWidth(int w) { width = w; }
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Paragraph& p) {
         int nextWord = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < p.nwords; i++) {
             if (nextWord + p.word[i].nLetters() > p.width) {
                 os << '\n';
                 nextWord = 0;
             }
             cout << p.word[i];
             nextWord += p.word[i].nLetters() + 1;
         }
         return os;
     }
     Paragraph& operator+=(const char* w) {
         if (nwords < mwords) {
             cout << "\n+=";
             word[nwords] = w;  // calls Word constructor, then Word = operator
             nwords++;
         }
         return *this;
     }
 };

 int main() {

     Paragraph p;
     cout << "--------\n";
     p.make(5);
     p += "This";
     p += "is";
     p += "hard";
     cout << "\n--------\n";
     cout << p << endl;
     cout << "--------\n";
     Paragraph q = p;
     q.setWidth(6);
     q += "too";
     cout << "\n--------\n";
     cout << q << endl;
     cout << "---------------\n";
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor is right. You don't need another operator since a `const char*` is directly (and implicitly) convertible to a `Word`, through:

```
Word(const char* s)
```

This is called a **conversion constructor**. If you declare it as `explicit`, it should no longer compile. See here - http://ideone.com/brjIi

So on the line

```
word[nwords] = w;
```

a temporary `Word` is indeed created from `w`, and then the assignment operator for `Word` is called to assign the temporary to `words[nwords]`.

Some other notes on the code:

- since your professor teaches you C++, you should learn about `std::string` and `std::vector`. He doesn't need C++ nor classes to demonstrate the power of pointers or dynamic memory allocation.
- statements like `if (word != NULL) delete [] word;` are redundant. `delete` or `delete[]` on a `NULL` pointer is guaranteed to work (and not do anything).
- the logic in the constructor is wrong (wouldn't be if you didn't manage memory yourself). After you construct a `Paragraph`, it's unusable until you call `make()`, which is bad design.

Comment: Thank you! So let me see if I understand your point: If you create a constructor for a class that takes a single parameter of a different object/variable type, it can be converted to an object of that class?  Under what conditions is this conversion possible?

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response - you said: 

**the logic in the constructor is wrong (wouldn't be if you didn't manage memory yourself).**

Which constructor are you referring to?

Comment: @keydude first question - yes, that is called a conversion constructor - look it up. Second question - the constructor of `Paragraph` - it creates an unusable object.